# Making thin BottomAppBar in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I made an BottomAppBar in HubPage in Windows Phone 8.1 app, but it is rater thick even though it has only one secondary command. How can I make CommandBar thin as in MSN News app for example (only one thin bar with `...` at the end).

I tried setting Height and MaxHeight to 0 but nothing helped.

Here is the code snippet of my CommandBar

```
    <CommandBar>
                <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                    <AppBarButton Label="{Binding Translations.settings}" 
                                  Icon="Setting" 
                                  Click="SettingsBarButton_Click"/>
                </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
     </CommandBar>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a thin bar when closed, by changing its [ClosedDisplayMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.closeddisplaymode.aspx):

```
<CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal" >
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Label="{Binding Translations.settings}" Icon="Setting" Click="SettingsBarButton_Click"/>
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```